# IOS - UISegmentationControl Set Image for both IOS6 and IOS7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

Here I used UISegmentationControl, I need to set the image for segmentation.In ios7, the images are placed in correct position but in ios6 and earlier versions the images are in incorrect sizes, please see the attached images

In IOS6 the images are in wrongly displayed images

[image: IOS6]
In IOS7 the images are in correct way

[image: IOS7]

Code I used to set the images as

```
UIImage *separator;
UIImage *onstate;
UIImage *offstate;
UIImage *unselected_right_state;
UIImage *unselected_left_state;

if ([UIImage instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(imageWithRenderingMode:)]) {
    separator = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"gseprator.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    onstate = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"on.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    offstate = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"off.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    unselected_right_state = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"gon2.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    unselected_left_state = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"goff1.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
}
else {
    separator = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gseprator.png"];
    onstate = [UIImage imageNamed:@"on.png"];
    offstate = [UIImage imageNamed:@"off.png"];
    unselected_right_state = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gon2.png"];
    unselected_left_state = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goff1.png"];
}

    if (true) {
        [[cell onoffSegment] setImage:onstate forSegmentAtIndex:0];
        [[cell onoffSegment] setImage:unselected_right_state forSegmentAtIndex:1];
    }else{
        [[cell onoffSegment] setImage:unselected_left_state forSegmentAtIndex:0];
        [[cell onoffSegment] setImage:offstate forSegmentAtIndex:1];
    }
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you're using a `UISegmentedControl` to handle on/off states when a `UISwitch` would suffice?

Comment: The client needs this kind of design, when I try use the UISwitch its different from client design, so that i used the UISegmentationControl